# Sphinx: How to stop a query submitted?

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

In sphinx, Sometimes there is a situation that a query takes a long time to complete. Is there any way to cancel submitted query or stop it somehow with SphinxQL? (I don't want to kill or stop searchd deamon and just want to kill thread that is running the query).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an explicit kill command.

If have slow queries perhaps consider using max_query_time option to prevent these in the first place.